# /r in sed shell script

Tags: shell, replace, sed

I am updating a C shell script that uses a sed command:

```
sed '/EOF/r $thingToAdd' $fileToAddItTo > $newFileOutput
```

I can't seem to find what the /r command means or does.  I think it is for a find and replace (similar to `/s..../g`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r` is used to read a file and append it at the current point.

The point in your example is the address `/EOF/` which means this script will find the line containing `EOF` and then append the file specified by `$thingToAdd` after that point. Then it will process the rest of the file.

In other words:

```
$fileToAddItTo  +  $thingToAdd  =  $newFileOutput
--------------     -----------     --------------
1                  5               1
2                  6               2
3                                  3
EOF                                EOF
4                                  5
                                   6
                                   4
```

You can see this in action in the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat file1 ; echo === ; cat file2
file1_line:1
file1_line:2
file1_line:3
file1_line:4 EOF
file1_line:5
===
file2_line:1
file2_line:2

pax$ sed '/EOF/r file2' file1
file1_line:1
file1_line:2
file1_line:3
file1_line:4 EOF
file2_line:1
file2_line:2
file1_line:5
```

---

And, in response to the question in your comment about whether it will do this for *every* line containing the `EOF` string, yes it will:

```
pax$ cat file1 ; echo === ; cat file2
file1_line:1
file1_line:2 EOF
file1_line:3
file1_line:4 EOF
file1_line:5
===
file2_line:1
file2_line:2

pax$ sed '/EOF/r file2' file1
file1_line:1
file1_line:2 EOF
file2_line:1
file2_line:2
file1_line:3
file1_line:4 EOF
file2_line:1
file2_line:2
file1_line:5
```

And, it will do it for every line *containing* the `EOF` string. Normally you would restrict something like this to lines containing *only* the `EOF` string since that's usually how it's set up (with the `EOF` being the only contents of that line). You could do that simply by changing the address to `/^EOF$/` (the `^` and `$` are the start-of-line and end-of-line anchors respectively).

Otherwise it would pick up lines you might not expect, like those containing `HEREOF`, `WRITEOFF` or `NEOFACISM`.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean the file $thingToAdd should be inserted wherever EOF is in $fileToAddItTo?